# ¿Cómo creo una consulta de un objeto en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Estoy aprendiendo javascript y vengo a las trompadas... Tengo que entregar un ejercicio sobre Objetos.
Mi idea era hacer un "programa" en donde un empleado pueda buscar la información sobre un cliente y su vehículo.
Llego a hacer que el navegador genere el cartel solicitando que se ingrese el cliente pero no se me ocurre cómo hacer para que trabaje. Yo quiero que el usuario por ejemplo ingrese *cliente2* y salga un `document.write` o un `console.log` con el cliente solicitado.

---

Este es mi código que está super rancio:

```
function solicitarCliente() {
  let clienteSolicitado = prompt("Por favor ingrese el cliente entre el 1 y 6 que desea buscar. Ejemplo: cliente1");
  
  
}

function Cliente (nombre, apellido, direccion, telefono, dni, vehiculo) {
  this.nombre = nombre;
  this.apellido = apellido;
  this.direccion = direccion;
  this.telefono = telefono;
  this.dni = dni;
  this.vehiculo = vehiculo;
}

function Vehiculo (marca, modelo, año, matricula, color) {
  this.marca = marca;
  this.modelo = modelo;
  this.año = año;
  this.matricula = matricula;
  this.color = color;
}




// creacion en duro de los objetos

//cliente 1
const vehiculo1 = new Vehiculo('Fiat', 'Uno', '1992', 'ALR-235', 'Verde');
const cliente1 = new Cliente('Juan', 'Perez', '12 blabal', '4444-5555', '32.474.111', vehiculo1);
console.log(cliente1);


//cliente2
const vehiculo2 = new Vehiculo('Ford', 'Escort', '1998', 'BJL-989', 'Gris');
const cliente2 = new Cliente('Alfredo', 'Garcia', 'Cosquin 4932', '4444-1111', '29.555.555', vehiculo2);
console.log(cliente2);


//cliente3
const vehiculo3 = new Vehiculo('Chevrolet', 'Clasic', '2016', 'JJJ-212', 'Negro');
const cliente3 = new Cliente('Veronica', 'Ñoquis', 'Zuviria 878', '4444-2222', '38.210.235', vehiculo3);
console.log(cliente3);


//cliente4
const vehiculo4 = new Vehiculo('Jeep', 'Renegade', '2020', 'HYT-789', 'Blanco');
const cliente4 = new Cliente('Guillermo', 'Rodrigues', 'Av. Directorio 788 ', '4444-8787', '31.252.147', vehiculo4);
console.log(cliente4);



//cliente5
const vehiculo5 = new Vehiculo('Ford', 'Focus', '2009', 'HLR-235', 'Azul');
const cliente5 = new Cliente('Yamila', 'Fenux', 'Milonga 989', '4444-3333', '38.210.775', vehiculo5);
console.log(cliente5);



//cliente6
const vehiculo6 = new Vehiculo('BMW', 'M3', '2010', 'WLR-205', 'Negro');
const cliente6 = new Cliente('Jorge', 'Discord', 'Alfarero 2912', '4444-6666', '32.589.121', vehiculo6);
console.log(cliente6);



let solicitud= solicitarCliente();
```

Comment: Lo mas sencillo es guardar los datos del cliente y vehiculo en la base de datos del navegador